# Change TextView from another XML

Tags: android, xml

I my app, I have somes XML. I want to modify a TextView, but it is not in the primary XML file for this Activity.

I tried:

```
TextView nav_playerid = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nav_username);
nav_playerid.setText(id_joueur_connect);
```

But that won't work. How can I tell the app to get this specific XML File and modify this TextView?

Comment: You have to load the other XML using `setContentView` for that to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An unqualified `findViewById` will search the present `contentView` of the Activity

> to get this specific XML File

You need to inflate the other one.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.other_layout, null);

// See 'v.findViewById'
TextView nav_playerid = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.nav_username);
nav_playerid.setText(id_joueur_connect);
```

But that creates a new, blank layout, so you'd also need to add that inflated view to the content view of the activity in order to see it.